# Biblatex - How to change format of journal, volume and page numbers in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm a little bit stuck in my attempts to change the format of my journal articles in my biblatex biography.

What i have so far:

```
Smith, A. and Smith, J. (2006). Article title. Journal title 29.2, pp. 1-43.
```

What is the goal:

```
Smith, A. and Smith, J. (2006). Article title. Journal title, 29(2): 1-43.
```

and (if there is no issue defined):

```
Smith, A. and Smith, J. (2006). Article title. Journal title, 29: 1-43.
```

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=50,firstinits=true,uniquelist=false,uniquename=init,isbn=false,doi=false,useprefix=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1} 
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{initials,
  author = {Doe, J. P. and Jones, J.},
  title = {An article coauthored by John-Paul Doe},
  journal = {Journal title},
  volume = {29},
  pages = {825--833},
  year = {2008}}
@Article{smitha,
  author = {Smith, Anne and Smith, Joe},
  title = {Article title},
  journal = {Journal title},
  volume = {29},
  number = {2},
  pages = {1--43},
  year = {2006}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{initials,smitha}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code should do what you want (with a suggestion of @Moewe):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=50,firstinits=true,uniquelist=false,uniquename=init,isbn=false,doi=false,useprefix=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
 \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}}
  {%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \iffieldundef{series}}{}{}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{initials,
  author = {Doe, J. P. and Jones, J.},
  title = {An article coauthored by John-Paul Doe},
  journal = {Journal title},
  volume = {29},
  pages = {825--833},
  year = {2008}}
@Article{smitha,
  author = {Smith, Anne and Smith, Joe},
  title = {Article title},
  journal = {Journal title},
  volume = {29},
  number = {2},
  pages = {1--43},
  year = {2006}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewcommand\bibpagespunct{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addcomma}\space}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}
  \printfield[parens]{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\begin{document}
\cite{initials,smitha}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think redefining the bibstrings for pages to be empty (or a space) is less than ideal, a change like `\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}` or `\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\ifentrytype{article}{#1}{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]{#1}}}` seems much more elegant. You might also want to make the change of `\bibpagespunct` type-dependant.

Comment: @Moewe: I thought the treatment should be global, for the sake of coherence. But maybe I wasn't able to imagine situations for which there should be another formatting… You're right, your suggestion is much mmore elegant, I'll retain it.

Comment: Yes, the type-dependency might have an element of inconsistency, but seems to be widely accepted (CMS & MLA handle `@articles` differently, I think). Since the OP seems to have embraced `\ifentrytype{article}` already in their MWE and the question mentioned only `@article`s I found it natural to change only those.

Comment: @Moewe: OK, you've convinced me. Answer modified.

Comment: Your way of making `\DeclareFieldFormat` type-dependant is of course much better than the crude attempt I suggested above. But now you delete the punctuation before the pages field entirely for non-`@article`s, maybe you wanted something like `renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon\space}{\addcomma\space}}`

Comment: Modified (slightly shorter than you version — hope there's no side effect).

Comment: Again, that change is more elegant than what I suggested (I wouldn't have thought there to be a side effect, but one can never be sure). Though the difference is not as drastic compared to the other one.

Comment: Thank you both very much! Just one quick question: How can i get a "," between the journal title and the volume? (See my question above)

Comment: That feature was added. One must use the `xpatch` package for that. See my updated answer.

Comment: what if you want something like "5 no. 4" or just "5" if there's no issue number? tried a few obvious extensions to the above with no success.

Comment: @ben w: You can replace the re-definition of  `volume+number+eid` bibmacro with the following:
   `\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{
      \printfield{volume}
      \addcomma\space
      \iffieldundef{number}{}
     {\printtext{no\addnbthinspace\printfield{number}}}
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}
      \printfield{eid}}`