# Customized BibTeX bst - slash between "volume" and "number"

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to customize my bibliography to match the requirements of a journal, and by using makebst, I arrived at something that comes pretty close to what I need. However, makebst, while offering some options for the appearance of "volume" and "number" in journal articles, does not offer to have the two entries separated by a slash (like: "32/4"). Right now, it gives "volume" and "number" as "32(4)". Is there an easy way to fix that?

Comment: The journal asks you to provide a bst? Don't journals usually have their own templates ready?

Comment: Which journal style are you trying to replicate?

Comment: Please show the contents of the function `format.vol.num.pages` that's in your bst file.

Comment: @Tiuri I asked them, they don't.

Comment: @samcarter The Philosophical Quarterly

Comment: @Mico FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "volume" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
  number "number" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      swap$ duplicate$ empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
        'skip$
      if$
      swap$
      "(" swap$ * ")" *
    }
  if$ *
}

Comment: please edit your posting to show the formatted function.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the biblatex package (I assume, you already do) and use \renewbibmacro (p. 203 biblatex manual) or \DeclareFieldFormat.

There is an example for code and output. If you read the manual and other Q&As like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238204/biblatex-how-to-change-format-of-journal-volume-and-page-numbers-in-bibliogra) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles), I am sure, you'll be able to customize it exactly the way you want it.

```
\documentclass[A4]{scrartcl}%
\usepackage[%
style=authoryear,%
backend=biber,%
uniquename=false,% 
uniquelist=false,% 
doi=false,%
isbn=false,%
url=false,%
eprint=false,%
]{biblatex}%
\usepackage{csquotes}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
\printfield{volume}%
\setunit{\addnbthinspace\slash\addnbthinspace}%
\printfield{number}%
\setunit{\addcomma}%
\printfield{eid}}%

%\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\slash{#1}} %a second way to change the number field and its delimiters

\usepackage{filecontents}%
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Name.2016,%
author = {Author, Name},%
year = {2016},%
title = {{National cross-sectional study of nothing}},%
pages = {543-548},%
pagination = {page},%
volume = {105},%
journaltitle = {Acta rediculanda},%
number = {11}%
}%
\end{filecontents}%

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}%

\begin{document}%
\cite{Name.2016}%
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]%
\end{document}%
```

Output:
[image: Output with slash between number and issue]

Answer (score 1):

In the .bst, I changed the entry `FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}` to

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "volume" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
  number "number" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      swap$ duplicate$ empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
        'skip$
      if$
      swap$
      "/" swap$ *
    }
  if$ *
}
```

That does it nicely.

Comment: It would have been helpful if you had posted the original BibTeX code as well.

Comment: Yes, I guess. Sorry!